# Is there a VSCode extension for VBscript that can create an outline?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vba

Visual Studio Code: There is some support for VBscript already built in.

And I know there exist several extensions for VBscript  that can do even better syntax highlighting, but is there one that can fill the "Outline View" panel in Visual Studio Code?

currently I am using VSCode v1.41.1 on linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging in the VSCode Extensions Marketplace I've found extension ["VBScript symbols"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=andreaslenzen.vbscript-language-server-client) by Andreas Lenzen.

(I've searched for "VBA" instead of "VBS")

The extension can fill the outline view in VScode. The most-installed extensions designed for VBS can't do this.